# Curved Container with fixed and percentage width interior columns

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a multi column container with a curved top? The complexity here is there is a left column fixed width (different background than other two columns). The curve is the particular problem.

The image below illustrates the issue. The "red" line is to reference the slight curve to the container. The fixed width column doesn't allow a simple curved image to be placed on top of the container.

Border radius (to my knowledge) cannot create the *slight* curve. Not sure what else is possible. Can you create an inverted mask curve on the image and position it over the container to get the same effect?

Here is a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qxhcy4hr/) mock-up of the layout below.

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you:

[Jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qxhcy4hr/2/)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.bannerImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://www.perfectlitter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/6784063-cute-cats-hd.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #787878;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.leftCol {
  width: 175px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}
.mainContent {
  padding-left: 175px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.midCol {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.rightCol {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 500px;
}
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
  top: -10px;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bannerImage"></div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="leftCol"></div>
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="midCol"></div>
      <div class="rightCol"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="leftCol"></div>
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="midCol"></div>
      <div class="rightCol"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alireza, I did use this method with some adjustments. I needed to achieve a more symmetrical curve so I extended width of div.circle past the wrapper to get this effect. Added a internal container and centered both. Here is a general idea for anyone that comes across. http://fiddle.jshell.net/s5yp6zdq/1/

Comment: @JavierCortez I'm sorry to replay late. You are welcome. Good job.